# Less mixin based on media query

Tags: css, less, sprite, mixins

I have two sprites:

- One with icons for "normal" resolution;
- One with icons for "high" resolution;

And I generated Less files with the following mixins:

For "normal sprite":

```
   .sprite-icon_back() {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background: url('/Content/icons/mobile-icons-sprite.png') 0 0;
    }

    .sprite-icon_access() {
        width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
        background: url('/Content/icons/mobile-icons-sprite.png') 0 -25px;
    }
```

For "high sprite":

```
   .sprite-icon_back() {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: url('/Content/icons/HighRes/mobile-icons-sprite-high.png') 0 0;
    }

    .sprite-icon_access() {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: url('/Content/icons/HighRes/mobile-icons-sprite-high.png') -100px 0;
    }
```

Class names:

```
.m-icon-back {
    .sprite-icon_back();
}

.m-icon-access{
    .sprite-icon_access();
}
```

So, I would like to use high mixin when the following media query is detected:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
}
```

How could I change the `background-image` (png file) based on that media query? I don't really know if this is possible like that but I am open to new solutions/alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@media` stuff is evaluated by browsers thus you can't use it as a condition for Less mixins. So the only way to handle this is to put a ruleset, a mixin or just a property of interest *into* the `@media` block of interest, e.g. for this use-case the simplest (but not necessary most optimal) solution would be something like this:

```
.sprite-icon_back() {

    // default properties:
    width:  25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url('/Content/icons/mobile-icons-sprite.png') 0 0;

    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
           only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
           only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        // properties for the high resolution media:
        width:  100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: url('/Content/icons/HighRes/mobile-icons-sprite-high.png') 0 0;
    }
}

// usage:

.m-icon-back {
    .sprite-icon_back();
}
```

with the following CSS output:

```
.m-icon-back {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: url('/Content/icons/mobile-icons-sprite.png') 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .m-icon-back {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('/Content/icons/HighRes/mobile-icons-sprite-high.png') 0 0;
  }
}
```

And repeating `@media` code (when you'll need the same code for other mixins) is further to be optimized with variables and/or [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature). For example like this:

```
.high-res-media(@styles) {
    @media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        @styles();
    }
}

.sprite-icon_back() {
    width:  25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url('/Content/icons/mobile-icons-sprite.png') 0 0;
    .high-res-media({
        width:  100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: url('/Content/icons/HighRes/mobile-icons-sprite-high.png') 0 0;
    });
}
```

### -

Also see an alternative method in this **[codepen](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JeDax)** suggested by **@Harry** in comments.

(I suppose there're ways to combine both methods to a certain degree to benefit from both but it's another story for a whole new book).

Comment: +1 mate. Just to pick your brains, is [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JeDax) way of writing this not advisable?

Comment: @Harry, I think your codepen could be an answer too. The difference is that your method is *more* optimal for the CSS output while my method is more bloating for the result but more DRY for the Less code itself.